# Play Framework: Html Template content not escaping properly

Tags: html, templates, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

im trying to populate a list in an html template using a prexisting module

```
@{Nav.list.map( l => 
    l.id match {
        case "Art" => { <li id="art"><span>Articles</span></li> }
        case "Due" => { <li id="toggle"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Links"><span>Links</span></a>
                            <div id="drawer">
                                <div id="drawerContent" style="display:none;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="link hover"><span>link title 2</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="link hover"><span>link title 3</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="link hover"><span>link title 4</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li> } 
        case _ => {     <li id="@l.id"><a href="@l.href" title="@l.title"><span>@l.title</span></a></li> }
    } )}
```

the @ isnt functioning as an escape character for the final case and instead just gets parsed as @l.id etc i originally did this with nested if else statements with very verbose brackets and that worked but wasnt very nice on the eyes, i think the formatter is having problems with nested scala constructs but im not sure.

i tried using for instead of map and tried enclosing and escaping the match construct, they compile but the issue still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are in scala world when doing @{}, thus you can do the following in the last case:

`case _ => <li id={l.id}><a href={l.href} title={l.title}><span>{l.title}</span></a></li>`

Alternatively I think you can do:
`@Nav.list.map( l => ... )`